# Spinner with customer adapter throwing Resources$NotFoundException when dropdown is clicked in Android

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-adapter

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am working with spinner view. But I am using spinner view with custom adapter because my spinner with will be more complicated soon. All the data for spinner come from server through volley. My spinner view with customer adapter is showing the data properly. But the problem is when I click the dropdown to choose item. It throws exception.

This is my customer adapter for spinner view:

```
public class SpinnerItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NVItem> {
    private ArrayList<NVItem> values;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> selectedValues;

    static class ViewHolder{
        public RadioButton radioButton;
        public TextView title;
    }

    public SpinnerItemAdapter(Context contextParam,ArrayList<NVItem> itemsParam,ArrayList<String> selectedParam)
    {
        super(contextParam,-1,itemsParam);
        this.values = itemsParam;
        this.context = contextParam;
        this.selectedValues = selectedParam;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View rowView = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(rowView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item,null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.radioButton = (RadioButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_radio);
            viewHolder.title = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_title);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder  = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        //rowView.setId(values.get(position).getId());
        viewHolder.title.setText(values.get(position).getName());
        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return values.size(); }
    @Override
    public NVItem getItem(int position) { return values.get(position); }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }
}
```

This is how I open spinner dialog and set adapter on button click in Android:

```
private void showCategorySpinner()
    {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_spinner,null);
        Spinner categorySpinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.chooser_spinner);
        ArrayList<NVItem> items = new ArrayList<NVItem>();
        for(int i=0;i<categoryItems.size();i++)
        {
            NVItem item = new NVItem();
            item.setId(categoryItems.get(i).getId());
            item.setName(categoryItems.get(i).getName());
            items.add(item);
        }
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new SpinnerItemAdapter(getBaseContext(),items,new ArrayList<String>());
        categorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateItemActivity.this);
        b.setView(view);
        b.show();
    }
```

Above function is called when button that open spinner dialog is clicked.

All data binding to spinner and opening spinner dialog works find. As in the screenshot below. But it throws error when the button that is circled in the screenshot is clicked.

This is screenshot:

[image]

This is the errors in logcat when that dropdown arrow is clicked:

```
03-17 22:26:37.925 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion W/ResourceType: No known package when getting value for resource number 0xffffffff
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa61c8908)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2139)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:853)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:415)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:737)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:733)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:681)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:959)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:609)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-17 22:29:01.685 32568-32568/com.blog.waiyanhein.mmfashion.mmfashion E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is wrong with my code?

### Edit

When I change the constructor of Adapter like this

```
super(contextParam,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,valuesParam);
```

List items appear like below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to change your adapter except to implement `getDropDownView()` in your adapter -

```
@Override
     public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
             ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
      View dropDownView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dropdown, parent, false);

      TextView view1 = (TextView)dropDownView.findViewById(<view_id>);
      view1.setText(values.get(position).getName());

      return dropDownView;

     }
```

where `R.layout.dropdown` is the layout xml for the dropdown view.It can be any UI  - simple or complex.

Comment: I tried on it converting from -1 to 0. But it throws the same error.

Comment: Try - ArrayAdapter adapter = new SpinnerItemAdapter(CreateItemActivity.this,items,new ArrayList<String>());

Comment: Edited my answer. You need to set DropDownView resource layout id. It can be any custom layout. I used android default - android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1

Comment: I tried this way . ArrayAdapter adapter = new SpinnerItemAdapter(CreateItemActivity.this,items,new ArrayList<String>());. It is not working

Comment: How to set DropDownView resource layout id please? I am beginner to android.

Comment: I edited the question. Please check new issue. Why ?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. It works . But cannot select item in dropdown. When I click on the item of dropdown, clicked item is not selected. Dropdown is not closed as well.

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84