# Android - Spinner not showing String value from inner class but inner class name

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, inner-classes

I'm facing a strange issue with a `Spinner` in my app. I've already looked up online but I couldn't get any solution.
I found a similar issue 
[here (edited part)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072859/spinner-with-customer-adapter-throwing-resourcesnotfoundexception-when-dropdown), but no one ever answered at that specific part of the question.

In my activity I have two Spinners: one showing a list of `LocalDate` objects and the other one showing "innocent" `String` objects retrieved from the inner class of a custom object. Both spinners share the same adapter class which I made extend `ArrayAdapter<Class<? extends Object>>` because I need it flexible.

The LocalDate spinner works fine.

But you can see what I'm getting from the other one when I click in order to show the spinner popup:

[image: Spinner issue]

I tried to put a log in order to print the value I'm getting, but log shows no issue at all, and at item selection the data is correctly put into the Spinner TextView.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: you do have to override toString() of the Model class for the spinner to display the required value. could you paste the code please

Answer (score 0):

I've just realized that I had to override the `getDropdownView()` method in order to get things right in the dropdown popup as well!

After all, the first Spinner wasn't working as expected neither but I thought it was something else.